# Ruby Geocoding Gem results methods/hash reference

Tags: ruby, google-maps, rubygems, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

```
result = Geocoder.search("white house, Washington DC")
```

How do you reference the below attributes?

I have tried `r.first.data["address_components"]`, but I can not reference past this, for example, I want to pull the [type="premise"]["long_name"], etc.  If I want the county, I can use r.first.country and it works, but r.first.premise does not work.

```
 [#<Geocoder::Result::Google:0x007f9cda81e880
  @cache_hit=nil,
  @data=
   {"address_components"=>
     [{"long_name"=>"The White House",
       "short_name"=>"The White House",
       "types"=>["premise"]},
      {"long_name"=>"1600", "short_name"=>"1600", "types"=>["street_number"]},
      {"long_name"=>"Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest",
       "short_name"=>"Pennsylvania Ave NW",
       "types"=>["route"]},
      {"long_name"=>"Northwest Washington",
       "short_name"=>"Northwest Washington",
       "types"=>["neighborhood", "political"]},
      {"long_name"=>"Washington",
       "short_name"=>"D.C.",
       "types"=>["locality", "political"]},
      {"long_name"=>"District of Columbia",
       "short_name"=>"DC",
       "types"=>["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]},
      {"long_name"=>"United States",
       "short_name"=>"US",
       "types"=>["country", "political"]},
      {"long_name"=>"20500", "short_name"=>"20500", "types"=>["postal_code"]}],
    "formatted_address"=>
     "The White House, 1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500, USA",
    "geometry"=>
     {"bounds"=>
       {"northeast"=>{"lat"=>38.8979044, "lng"=>-77.0355124},
        "southwest"=>{"lat"=>38.8973144, "lng"=>-77.03795749999999}},
      "location"=>{"lat"=>38.8976094, "lng"=>-77.0367349},
      "location_type"=>"ROOFTOP",
      "viewport"=>
       {"northeast"=>{"lat"=>38.8989583802915, "lng"=>-77.03538596970849},
        "southwest"=>{"lat"=>38.8962604197085, "lng"=>-77.0380839302915}}},
    "partial_match"=>true,
    "place_id"=>"ChIJGVtI4by3t4kRr51d_Qm_x58",
    "types"=>["premise"]}>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the Geocoder::Result::Google class is here: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/alexreisner/geocoder/master/Geocoder/Result/Google It has lots of useful methods, including [`address_components_of_type`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/alexreisner/geocoder/master/Geocoder/Result/Google#address_components_of_type-instance_method).

It looks like what you want is this:

```
res1 = result.first
premises = res1.address_components_of_type(:premise)
puts premises[0]['long_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to my code and now it works well.

```
module Geocoder::Result
  class Google < Base

    def premise
       if premise = address_components_of_type(:premise).first
         premise['long_name']
       end
    end

    def premise_code
       if premise = address_components_of_type(:premise).first
         premise['short_name']
       end
    end

    def subpremise
       if subpremise = address_components_of_type(:subpremise).first
         subpremise['long_name']
       end
    end
    def subpremise_code
       if subpremise = address_components_of_type(:subpremise).first
         subpremise['short_name']
       end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: There's a good set of [docs for Geocoder::Results::Google](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/alexreisner/geocoder/Geocoder/Result/Google) available that has all the answers you'll want, I think.

Given your result above, this should work:

```
r = result.first
r.types
# => ["premise"]
r.country
# => "United States"
r.country_code
# => "US"
r.formatted_address
# => "The White House, 1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500, USA"
```